# python packet sniffer using raw socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

trying to create packet sniffer using raw socket in python, and want to parse the full TCP header using struct.unpack method, but some fields like HLEN(4bits) and offset, URG,ACK,PST,RST,SYN,FIN in tcp header are on bits not Byte . so my question is how to parse these values from header !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

- [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions) which is part of the standard library, or
- [`Construct`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_%28python_library%29) which is designed to support network protocols,
- [`bitarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) which isn't,
- [`bitstring`](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) which isn't as well.

Here is an example:

```
from ctypes import c_int32, c_uint32, Structure, Union

class _bits(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("odd", c_uint32, 1),
        ("half", c_uint32, 31),
    ]

class Int(Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("bits", _bits),
        ("number", c_uint32),
    ]


a = Int(number=12345)
a.bits.odd, a.bits.half
```

the result:

```
>>> a = Int(number=12345)
>>> a.bits.odd, a.bits.half
(1L, 6172L)
```